# Jquery UI slider displaying time format on page load?

Tags: jquery

Hello i have pasted together some code creating a time input using the slide in jquery UI. The code works fine but the value shows the numerical value instead on the hh:mm when the page is first loaded. Can any one tell me how to do this?

```
$(function() {

    $("#sliderTime2").slider({
        range: false,
        value: 720,
        min: 0,
        max: 1425,
        step: 15,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
            var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);
            if(hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
            if(minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
            $('#sliderTimeDis2').val(hours+':'+minutes);
        }
    });

     $("#sliderTimeDis2").val($("#sliderTime2").slider("value"));

});
```

Comment: Use "create" callback to set value, not slide.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're loading the value of the slider which would be an integer into your div.

You'll want something like this:

```
$(function() {

   $("#sliderTime2").slider({
      range: false,
      value: 720,
      min: 0,
      max: 1425,
      step: 15,
      slide: function(e, ui) {
         updateTimeDisplay(ui.value);
      },
      create: function(e, ui) {
         //this should work
         updateTimeDisplay($(this).option('value'));
      }
   });

   var updateTimeDisplay=function(timeVal)
   {
      var hours = Math.floor(timeVal / 60);
      var minutes = timeVal - (hours * 60);
      if(hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
      if(minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
      $('#sliderTimeDis2').val(hours+':'+minutes);
   }

});
```